# Code Annotation and Preview with HTML

Tags: html, code-snippets

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html

http://angularjs.org/#/list (the basics one)

Basically, I'm wondering what tools there are out there for me to create what they have there. The one I really like is he angularJS one, because I need a way to allow annotations within my code snippets.

So, basically. My question is this:

How did they create the annotations to work at certain places in the code (so you hover over the highlight), is that created from a library. If so, where is this library found? I found some online, but they all looked like terrible sticky notes, and I want something more stylish like this.

And finally, how do i get the line numbering to work?

Thank you.

Alex.